# How do I create and deploy custom settings for Salesforce, in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, deployment, salesforce, settings

I have some custom settings in my org, but I do not appear to be able to synchronise them with my project in Eclipse.  I've scanned the 'Add/Remove Metadata Components', but I can't find anything related to custom settings.  Nor can I find a new Force.com object of type Custom Settingngs.

I want to deploy my changes from Eclipse, to a different sandbox, but of course the custom settings are missing.

Is this just not possible or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom settings should be available as a custom object on the object's list.
Did you refresh your metadata definition from server? (take a look to marked button on the screenshot below)
[image]

Comment: Excellent thanks @Pavel. I take it it's possible to create custom setting, by creating a new custom object in Eclipse, it's just far easier to do it in the saleforce UI?

Comment: I guess that the salesforce UI is the more convenient way to manage custom settings.